# How can I get my regex method to return all path matches?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to parse out our backup paths, which are network shares, from the backup command used.

This is what the backup command looks like:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [UnitTestDB] TO DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_1.bak', DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_2.bak', DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_3.bak', DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_4.bak' WITH CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION
```

What I want is to get all of the network shares out....

```
\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_1.bak
\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_2.bak
\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_3.bak
\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_4.bak
```

No single quotes, just the values.

I can get it working on http://regexstorm.net/tester but I can't seem to translate it back to PowerShell terms. This is the matching expression that works in the tester...

```
[DISK = N'](\S*)[']
```

But PowerShell only returns one out of the four matches and it returns the `N'` as well. It has to be some syntax error I'm not catching.

Output:

```
Groups   : { N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_1.bak', 
           N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_1.bak}
Success  : True
Captures : { N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_1.bak'}
Index    : 38
Length   : 100
Value    :  N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_1.bak'
```

Here's the code I have so far...

```
$backupCommand = "BACKUP DATABASE [UnitTestDB] TO DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_1.bak', DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_2.bak', DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_3.bak', DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_4.bak' WITH CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION"

[regex]::Match($backupCommand,"[DISK = N'](\S*)[']")
```

Comment: have you tried using an array with global match ? 

example `@myarray = $myvar = ~m/(stuff you want to match regex)/g;` 
that is supposed to match what you want and put it in a group and feed to "myvar" variable then push that variable into the "myarray" array so all your addresses should be saved there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[regex]::Matches` instead of `Match` to get *multiple matches*. To get the capture group, you have to access the Property `Groups[1].Value`. Also, your regex was wrong, you have to omit the square brackets:

```
$backupCommand = "BACKUP DATABASE [UnitTestDB] TO DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_1.bak', DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_2.bak', DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_3.bak', DISK = N'\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_4.bak' WITH CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION"

[regex]::Matches($backupCommand,"DISK = N'(\S*)[']") | Foreach {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
}
```

**Output:**

```
\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_1.bak
\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_2.bak
\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_3.bak
\\networkshare\sqldb\servername\UnitTestDB\FULL\servername_UnitTestDB_FULL_20160614_231500_4.bak
```

---

This will work, but since your capture group will fail if the network path contains an empty space, I would change the regex to capture all until the trailing `'`:

```
DISK = N'([^']+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 2):

Lots of options when it comes to regex solutions. [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37841992/3829407) explains why you were not getting the results you expected and that you needed to return all results by using the static method `[regex]::Matches`. You can also use `Select-String` with the `-AllMatches` switch to do the same thing. Since it returns matchinfo objects you also need to do a little post processing.

I used a different regex based on your source data. Return matches between sets of double quotes. I could have made this more terse if I used lookaheads and behinds but I wanted to keep the regex simple.

```
$regex = "'(.*?)'"

($data | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches).Matches | 
    ForEach-Object{$_.Groups[1].Value}
```